# How do we deal with answers that become obsolete as the plot advances?

Tags: discussion

This question [Does Zetsu have a word soul?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/does-zetsu-have-a-word-soul/2224) received some good answers a few days back. However, with the Naruto chapter 618, these answers became obsolete or even incorrect. Nothing personal against the people who answered them, but how do we deal with such cases?

Clearly, we cannot restrict questions to completed series only, because that would be the end of this site. In the beginning, as there is a relatively small number of regular users, we may be able to have all the obsolete answers edited, but this is clearly not going to work as the number of users grows.

I have been thinking of what is a good way to handle it, but could not decide on anything.

**Edit** On second thoughts, I am undecided if the example given above really makes the old answers obsolete. However, regardless of the example being accurate or not, the question is still valid.

Comment: I think we'll add it to the discussion today. Come be with us on chat today at 21:00 UTC.

Comment: 21:00 UTC is 2:30 am (tomorrow) for me. I think I will have to pass. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a question with an established accepted answer, we should notify the answerer(s) via a comment and give them a chance to update their answer based on the latest development(s) and/or retcon(s).

If it's fairly new question or has no accepted answer, you can just add a new answer and note this new development/retcon in your answer.